# Add UIImageView as Subview

Tags: ios, imageview, subview

I'm trying to create an animated UIImageView with certain image constraints.

I want the UIImageView animating at a size of 141x262, and not the entire screen. Currently I have this code:

```
CJ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

CJ.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"CJ_1.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"CJ_2.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"CJ_3.png"], nil];

CJ.animationDuration = 1;
CJ.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[CJ startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:CJ];
```

Any and all help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you also using interface builder?

Comment: Yes I am using interface builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the view to be a different size, set its frame to be that size:

```
CJ = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 141, 162)];
```

If your images are large, you probably also want to set a contentMode on your view. For example:

```
CJ.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: Nope, it still takes up the entire screen.

Comment: I've added another suggestion

Comment: It's not that the image is huge, Xcode is stretching the image (I only want it to be the size it is). Xcode: http://cl.ly/I2eT  What I want: http://cl.ly/I2XX

Comment: You might need to use a different content mode (`UIViewContentModeCenter`?) or set the frame after you assign animationImages (`CG.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 141, 162)`). But if you're using Interface Builder, I'm not sure why you're making this view in code.

Comment: I tried Interface Builder first & I had no luck. Now that I'm trying it in code, I'm still having no luck.

Comment: Thanks Jesse Rusak! The UIViewContentModeCenter & the CGRectMake worked perfectly! :D